# PolyLang plugin not displaying Language switcher in Appearance->Menu

Tags: php, wordpress, polylang, language-switching

I've been trying to implement multilanguage support for my new website and I want to be able to have a language switcher next to my menu, like every other normal website. I have the following plugins:
Ocean Extra, Elementor, Polylang and WPForms Lite.

I don't know If I screwed it up somehow or what happened, but when I go to

`Appearance -> Menu -> Screen Options`

nothing happens. It's just a blank white space that expands by 10 pixels when I click on it and I cannot change anything. Here's an image of what happens when I click on Screen Options:
[image]

When I click on "Help" that is next to "Screen Options", it expands normally. So my question is how can I add this to my OceanWP theme? I have already translated all of my stuff, so I just need to place the language switcher, and it being on the footer is a sore pain for my eyes.
Does everyone else have this option for free? Or what is going on? Should I try reinstalling my whole site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstalled WordPress and then tried again, it worked. Although it didn't appear in the "Screen Options" menu, It appeared above "Pages" in the Appearance -> Menu

Answer (score 2):

You need to enable the language switcher

https://docs.themeisle.com/article/589-how-to-add-polylang-language-switcher-to-themes

Answer (score 1):

You can add the language switcher by updating your theme files, just add the following to the header or menu where you want the language switcher to appear:

```
<ul><?php pll_the_languages();?></ul>
```

You can also add the language switcher by widget.

To customize the language switcher, you can read [this documentation](https://polylang.wordpress.com/documentation/documentation-for-developers/functions-reference/).

Comment: I already read that craphole, OceanWP makes it really hard to put the piece of code on the right side of the menu, If you want to put it on easily, you have to check the "Language Switcher" option as I mentioned. If I were to completely reinstall my website, would I have the option "Language Switcher" in my Appearance -> Menus is my question or do I need to pay for Polylang Pro for that? I am that desperate

Comment: @Sibuscus maybe there is a theme or plugin compatibility issue, I just installed the polylang plugin on a clean WordPress install and I could see [the option on the menu section](https://i.imgur.com/KcQtLqY.png). Have you tried switching themes, disabling all plugins?

Comment: Completely reinstalled WP and it worked. Something must've bugged out or something fucky like that.